# Linux Shell - Sort a text file by the length of each line, then print the shortest line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, sorting

I have a file, `file.txt`, that contains the following:

```
This is many letters
This is few
Hi
This is a very long sentence.
```

(It actually is a few thousand lines long,
but I am new to Linux, and want to make it easy.)

I want to, only in shell, sort the list by the length of each line, either direction. Smallest first or last.

Then I want it to print the shortest line, "hi" and possibly tell me what line it is on, and the number of characters. How would I do this, preferably without using Awk?

Comment: Does "only in shell" mean you want to avoid `sort` as well?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `awk`? Is this homework?

Answer (score 4):

The commands

```
line_num=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "${#line} $((++line_num)) $line"
done < file.txt > tmpfile.txt
```

will create a file called `tmpfile.txt`, which looks like this:

```
20 1 This is many letters
11 2 This is few
2 3 Hi
29 4 This is a very long sentence.
```

where each line is preceded by its length and its line number. 
Then `sort -n tmpfile.txt` will yield:

```
2 3 Hi
11 2 This is few
20 1 This is many letters
29 4 This is a very long sentence.
```

which is sorted by line length. 
You can then send that to `head -n1` to get the first line
(i.e., the shortest line)
or `tail -n1` to get the last line (i.e., the longest line). 
Or use `sort -nr` to reverse the order,
so you can use `head -n1` to get the longest line. 
(This might be infinitesimally more efficient than using `tail`.)

If you want to see only the shortest line,
you can use a pipe and avoid creating the temporary file:

```
line_num=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "${#line} $((++line_num)) $line"
done < file.txt | sort -n | head -n1
```

This would probably be more efficient in `awk`.